# Database not getting updated with the Dataset

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, dataset, dataadapter

So, the problem I've is the data from my Dataset is not updating to the SQL server back.

The following is a function to Update License year (years) and cost (cost) for a specific license item (id) based on the input parameters.

Initially, I get the actual Expiration date and add the number of years from the input parameter years and then update the according license with the updated year and cost.

I'm creating a Adapter to select all the license and fill with the DataSet and then to update the same with the update command accordingly.

But, at the end the data is not getting updated.

Any ideas?

```
public void UpdateLicense(int id,int years,double cost)
    {
        try{
            SqlConnection conn = DBConnection.GetConnection();
            conn.Open();
            string PurDate="";
            SqlCommand sqlGetDate = new SqlCommand("select expiration_date from License where id ="+id, conn);
            SqlDataReader reader = sqlGetDate.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
                {
                    PurDate = (string)reader["EXPIRATION_DATE"];
                }
            }
            reader.Close();
            string updatedYear = DateTime.ParseExact(PurDate, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddYears(years).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            string sqlLicIns = "select * from License";
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlLicIns, conn);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("License");
            adapter.Fill(ds, "License");
            SqlCommand sqlLicUpd = new SqlCommand("update License set cost =" + cost + ", expiration_date='" + updatedYear + "' where id =" + id, conn);
            adapter.UpdateCommand = sqlLicUpd;
            adapter.Update(ds, "License");
            adapter.Dispose();
            sqlLicUpd.Dispose();
            conn.Close();
            }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `UpdatedYear` appears to be in the format 'dd/MM/yyyy'.  Normally, SQL dates are accessed as 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Comment: Is this an existing project or a new one?  If it's a new one, please consider using an ORM (EntityFramework).  You are writing code in a style that was out of date 10 years ago!

Comment: @Neil, Understand your point. Thanks for pointing the new technology. Unfortunately, this exercise is mandatory for my job learning. And, Am supposed to use only DataSet/Adapter the way they've asked for

Comment: It doesn't seem like you know how update works.  I don't use it very often, but from what i can tell your update command needs to be setup with parameters rather then hard coded values.  I would recommend looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/updating-data-sources-with-dataadapters   the first example should give you a better idea of how to achieve your goal.

Comment: Before you do anything else you need to read about, understand and start using parameterized queries. This patter you have here is extremely vulnerable to sql injection. My friend bobby tables loves code like this...http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: You should use Parameters for your Update Command ... and not place the values you want to update into the Update Sql Statement ... change the values in the DataSet/DataTable. DataAdapter.Update gets the changed Values from there.